# How to disable a switch to jacuzzi whirlpool tub

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, switch

I have a rental with a huge two persons jacuzzi whirlpool tub. I don’t want any renter to use it.
How do I disable the electric switch so that it has no power?

Comment: We need a lot more info, including, hopefully, pictures of the electrical connections, breaker panel, etc.  It depends a lot on how easily you want to be able to enable/disable the Jacuzzi on an at-need basis, and if the renter has access to the breaker panel.

Comment: As a landlord or a renter, most places will want/require a licensed electrician to do electrical work.

Answer (score 2):

A hot tub *should* have its own breaker if it was installed recently, but that would be the first thing to check.  Find the breaker that powers the hot tub and turn that off.  Check and see what else loses power, and if that's acceptable, that could be all you need.

Turning off a breaker is pretty obvious, so a renter might turn it back on.  To try and prevent that, breakers have "lock out" devices that can be added to the panel so you can put a small lock or tag on the breaker to prevent it from turning back on.

If you don't want to add that to the panel, a simple label or note saying that the circuit is damaged and shouldn't be turned on might be another good option.  People might think twice before turning on a bad circuit and jumping in water.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to drain and winterize the Jacuzzi unless you intend to go out there periodically to do the thing with chemicals and maintenance. If you don't, you'll end up with yet another "green pool" which basically breeds mosquitos, and the tenants will call the city.

After that is done, have your electrician open up the breaker panel and pull the supply wires off the breaker so the breaker does nothing.

### Actually, here's an idea that could make you some $$$.

Have the electrician use that same breaker to provide an EV charging outlet in the garage.  Now, you can say "We disconnected the jacuzzi permanently to provide EV charging."  The tenant will either say "snort, *great*, that doesn't help me" or "OMG, we picked this place and paid a higher rent *because it has that*. You rock, landlord!"

I leave it to you whether to use an $80 Hubbell socket and $150 GFCI breaker so the tenant can use their own "travel unit", versus ~$500 for a hard-wired, wall unit. *Normally that decision would be obvious, except there are substantial rebates on the hard-wired wall units that more than cover the difference*.  Nobody's giving rebates on sockets, because everyone who wants to power a welder or RV would abuse the rebate.

Comment: The catch with hardwired for a rental is that for the next 2 years or so it is a gamble what to install. After that it is no question Tesla/NACS. Which probably means "put in Tesla/NACS now" since they are ~ 2/3 of the existing fleet (or more).

Comment: @manassehkatz yes, and more complicatedly, up until last month everyone was convinced NACS was Betamax, so some rebates may require the J1772/Fetch connector. Texas already requires that on public chargers they subsidize.  But good news, with *even Volkswagen/Electrify America* switching to NACS/Tesla, those laws will probably fall. Eventually lol. Speed of government.  Yeah, imagine it's 1983 and the whole mob of VHS recorder makers, including JVC, said "switching to Beta. Beta is better."

Comment: We'll never know how much of an effect, because each individual purchase can have many different reasons, but I am **pretty sure** this is having a **big** effect on sales of non-Tesla EVs. Until Ford/GM/etc. start shipping an NACS adapter with every car (and be integrated into the Tesla payment ecosystem - though that probably isn't too hard since Tesla had to do the software work already for Magic Dock), I think an awful lot of people will either wait on buying an EV or just go with Tesla (even if it isn't their first choice based on features, price, etc.).

Comment: @manassehkatz I'm not sure purchase of a $50,000 vehicle will be too impeded by worrying about a $500 EVSE. Especially since most think the only 2 charging choices are a NEMA 5-15 socket, or a NEMA 14-50 socket, with the travel EVSE.  I do notice that Chevy is subsidizing installation of a 14-50 socket, *but not subsidizing* wall units.

Comment: It isn't the $500 EVSE. Someone who buys an EV and owns their own home can buy a new EVSE with the next (NACS) EVSE. OP's instance is rental - so it makes sense to play to the market. My main point is that if someone is in the market for an EV (with no prior allegiance to a particular brand) Tesla right now has MORE of an edge than before the adoption of NACS by others because of the Supercharger network. Prior to Ford/GM/etc. you could say "I'll get a Ford *anyway* because I like a normal pickup truck" or whatever. But now it has become "Should I buy this now or wait a year - because if I

Comment: wait then I get Supercharger access (and all the other new networks coming online/switching to NACS). It is kind of stupid because you could just buy an adapter (I am sure there will be plenty available in the next year or two) to charge at NACS, and is a drop in the bucket compared to the full cost of an EV. But people don't think that way. Little bits can make the difference - look at how Tesla manages demand with tiny tweaks like 3 months (Model 3) or 3 years (S/X) of Supercharging. Worth hardly anything but it sells cars.

Comment: @manassehkatz they're way ahead of you on that. People who buy cars today will get Supercharger access (MagicDocks only) as soon as they set that up, and they are making "personal MagicDock adapter" frobs they'll be mailing out to every existing owner as soon as production can ramp up.

Comment: I have a feeling that Tesla is not going to make nearly as many MagicDocks now as they would have if the Ford/GM/etc. deals had not  happened. But yeah, they will do a bunch of those. The "personal MagicDock" is going to be key  - that will help sales of non-Tesla vehicles and of residential Tesla EVSE.